# How to implement Pundit authorization for application with two devise models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails application which has two devise models. User and Admin. Both have separate logins and separate pages. But they sometimes uses same controllers. I want to implement pundit authorization for both devise models.
Im a rails newbie. How would I do this?

Comment: Treat them as though they were standard models.  Most of Pundit's policies are defined on the controller level.  A guide laying it all out is here: https://learn.co/lessons/devise_pundit_readme

Comment: But I need a more better explanation of how to implement pundit for multimodel devise rails application. @bkunzi01